# JAVA GRPC server side stream keeps increasing max-inbound-message-size

Tags: java, grpc, micronaut, grpc-java

What are the best practices of streaming lots of data with GRPC?
I am sending a request to a GRPC server that will stream back data. The data send back can be a in the order of 100 protobuf messages or can be a couple of 100.000 protobuf messages.

```
service CrossEngineSelector {
    rpc QueryDB (QueryRequest) returns (stream QueryResponse) {}
}
```

The server is a simple implementation that sends the protobuf messages.

```
@Override
public void queryBD(QueryRequest request, StreamObserver<QueryResponse> responseObserver) {

      Iterables.partition( dataLoader.getData(), 1000).forEach(batch -> {
          responseObserver.onNext(QueryResponse.newBuilder().addAllRows(batch).build());
      });
      responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
```

The client side uses a blockingStub that calls this method (generated code by protobuf):

```
public Iterator<QueryResponse> queryDB(QueryRequest request) {
            return ClientCalls.blockingServerStreamingCall(this.getChannel(),
                   CrossEngineSelectorGrpc.getQueryEnginesMethod(),
                   this.getCallOptions(), request);
}
```

Once the client calls this method I just iterate over the QueryResponse.

All of this works fine for streams that only send back a small amount of messages. Once I try to stream 100.000 messages the max-inbound-message-size keeps increasing and I end up with an error: `RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Compressed gRPC message exceeds maximum size 4194304: 4196022 bytes read`

My current fix for this is to set the max-inbound-message-size very high +1Gb. This is a hardcoded value, so it doesn't scale. The client has no idea how many messages the server will return. I might run into use cases were even the 1Gb max-inbound-message-size will not be enough.

I hope I am making an implementation mistake. I hope there is a way of resetting the message size for every stream (onNext()) from the server or is it normal it keeps increasing the message size?

I would assume that a single `responseObserver.onNext(QueryResponse.newBuilder().addAllRows(batch).build());` sends a couple of Mb and that this would be considered as the message size and not the entire stream for as long as it runs.

I am using Micronaut for both server and client.

Answer (score 2):

The `maxInboundMessageSize` is for protecting receiver going out of memory if malicious peer sends very large payload to attack. 
The real problem here is the 1000 chunks can be larger than 4MB (default `maxInboundMessageSize`).

you can fix this in two ways,

- fix the sender to limit by size of the payload, not by # of rows.
- or, the receiver have large enough `maxInboundMessageSize` to handle normal 1000 rows worth of data.

the later method is essentially what you implemented. It should be lower than 1GB+ though. gRPC won't use the `maxInboundMessageSize` amount of memory as I mentioned above this is purely for protecting. (added later)

Comment: This is indeed how I would expect it to work. However form my tests it looks like it takes the whole stream size as max-size.  

Excample: Streaming 10 Mb in 1 Mb chunks will result in an error after the 4th stream, unless you set max-inbound-message-size to 10Mb   

In my case I can always stream about 8500 lines and after that it crashes
`io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: gRPC message exceeds maximum size 4194304: 4335181`

Comment: grpc checks the frame size from the header of each http2 frame (see MessageDeframer#processHeader). So it is unlike happen (i hope =p) if you can create a minimal repro, we can definitely take a look.

Comment: Thanks you @creamsoup, after checking all the code again I found a mistake server side that was increasing the protobuf message with every iteration. All works as expected.